# Создать процедуру с параметром enum, но чтобы указать можно было разные enum

Tags: java, generics, vaadin, enum

У меня есть Grid в Vaadin. В качестве фильтра для столбцов добавляю ComboBox заполенный enum.

```
private enum CITY_LIST {
    Все, Тамбов, Орёл, Краснодар
}
private ComboBox getColumnFilterComoBox(final Object columnId, Grid p_grid, Enum en, Object val) {
        ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox();
        combobox.setInvalidAllowed(false);
        combobox.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
        combobox.setTextInputAllowed(false);
        //Заполняю ComboBox перечислением
        combobox.addItems(CITY_LIST.values());
        combobox.setValue(CITY_LIST.Все);
        combobox.setWidth("100%");
        combobox.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TEXTFIELD_TINY);
        combobox.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
                SimpleStringFilter filter = null;

                @Override
                public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
                    Filterable f = (Filterable) p_grid.getContainerDataSource();
                    // Remove old filter
                    if (filter != null) {
                        f.removeContainerFilter(filter);
                    }
                    //Какое то условие
                    if ((CITY_LIST)combobox.getValue() != CITY_LIST.Все) {
                        filter = new SimpleStringFilter(columnId, combobox.getValue().toString(),
                                true, false);
                        f.addContainerFilter(filter);

                        p_grid.cancelEditor();
                    }
                }
            });
        return combobox;
    }
```

В примере указано перечисление CITY_LIST. Как мне изменить функцию чтобы передавать во входных параметрах перечисление, которым заполняется ComboBox и значение которое должно быть выбрано. Как это сделать изящно и не потерять проверку значений при компиляции? 
P.S. Столбцов таких несколько десятков, в разных таблицах.

Answer (score 4):

Это можно сделать так:

```
private <T extends Enum<T>> ComboBox getColumnFilterComboBox(
        final Object columnId, Grid p_grid, Class<T> enumClass, final T value
    ) {
    ...
    combobox.addItems(enumClass.getEnumConstants());
    combobox.setValue(value);
    ...
    //Какое то условие
    if (combobox.getValue() != value) {
    }
}
```